# Multiplication in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am new to Redshift, trying to do multiplication in my SQL as mentioned below

```
Case  When COALESCE(height * width * length * weight, 0) = 0 then ...
```

getting below error message,

> Invalid operation: Resulting scale overflows maximum precision
>   Details:

Can someone please guid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Redshift document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html):

> precision
>
> The total number of significant digits in the whole value:
> the number of digits on both sides of the decimal point. For example,
> the number 48.2891 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4. The default
> precision, if not specified, is 18. The maximum precision is 38.

So I think it depends on what's current precision of your data type. One way to work around is casting:

```
Case When COALESCE(height::decimal(8,3) * width::decimal(8,3) * length::decimal(8,3) * weight::decimal(8,3), 0) = 0 then ...
```